# Scala: concise syntax for constructing `Map` that assigns int-values to characters?

Tags: scala, dictionary, set, flatmap

I want to define a `Map` that assigns values to letters like so:

- `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` should be assigned value `1`
- `'D'`, `'E'`, `'F'` should be assigned value `2`

etc.

Here is what I tried:

```
   def lettersAndValues = Map(
     1 -> Set('A', 'B', 'C'),
     2 -> Set('D', 'E', 'F'),
   ).flatMap {case (value, letters) => letters.map(letter =>(letter, value))}
```

Now I want to use the values of the letters to compute a score for words, for instance calculating the value of `"ABCD"` should give `1+1+1+2 = 5`. How can I define the score function? Are there other more concise ways to assign values to letters for calculations?

Comment: Need help with the title not exactly sure what to name this question?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the actual question is? If you want to map names to integers, why don't you simply set `Map('A' -> 1, ..., 'F' -> 2)`? What is the `map` method in your code? What's your actual goal, maybe start with that...

Comment: Similar instance to a game of scrabble, where letters are assigned values. BED will have a score of 5. And exactly what you did with Map just assigning a bunch together.

Comment: Alright, and then what exactly is your problem? What's not working? Or do you have some idea of a syntax that you would like to use, but do not know how to implement? Then write down what you want to achieve.  Please describe the concrete problem. "Implement Scrabble" is way too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to quickly define values of many letters, and then define a score function, here is a shorter way to do this:

```
val letterToValue = List(
  "ABC" -> 1,
  "DEF" -> 2
).flatMap{
  case (letters, value) => letters.map(letter => (letter, value))
}.toMap

def score(word: String) = word.map(letterToValue).sum

println(score("BED"))
println(score("BAD"))
println(score("CAFEBABE"))
```

It prints:

```
5
4
11
```

Comment: @JordanCutler With `postfixOps` it could now even be written as `word map letterToValue sum`... But let's not try to make it look too much like natural language, I personally find it clear enough^^

Answer (score 0):

A for-comprehension approach:

```
val generatorMap = Map(
  "ABC" -> 1,
  "DEF" -> 2
)
val letterToValue: Map[Char, Int] = for {
  (ls, v) <- generatorMap
  l <- ls
} yield {
  (l, v)
}

def score(word: String) = word.map(letterToValue).sum
```